# Версия log4j с org.apache.logging.log4j

Tags: maven, java, log4j

Какую версию прописать в maven, для того чтобы мог импортировать org.apache.logging.log4j?
Кучу версий перебрал, но возможно импортировать только java.util.logging.Logger. На данный момент прописана версия 2.1.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Не в том модуле были прописаны dependency